# Where has my ASP.NET State Service disappeared to?

Tags: asp.net, webserver

I set my ASP.NET State service to automatic start the other day on a hosted VSP Win 2003 server. I came back today and the service has gone completely missing!?

Any ideas why it has gone and how to get it back? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your hosting service provider, they may have removed it (for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, that the ASP.NET State service disappeared from the Administrative Tools / Services list. And the command "net start aspnet_state" didn't work either.

For me it worked fine after doing a repair on the currently latest .net version. Net 4.0 in my case.